# How to set multiple rate limits , per 10sec, per 10min, per 1 day using django-ratelimit or throttling?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, throttling, rate-limiting

I want to set the rate limits for my views based on duration of 10sec, 10min and 1 day. So let say user can send 20 requests/ 10 sec, 100 requests/ 10min and 1000 request per day.

I have tried throttling but couldn't find any way to set multiple requests. 
I have tried django-ratelimit package, but i couldn't find any such option in that too as it sets a single string for rate, such as rate = '5/10m'.
Please let me know if there is any way out to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the [documentation on **`django-ratelimit`**](https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#examples). You can define multiple `@ratelimit` decorators on the same view.

Furthermore the format of a rate allows you to add a [number to the denominator](https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rates.html#simple-rates):

> You may also specify a number of units, i.e.: **`X/Yu` where `Y` is a number of units**. If `u` is omitted, it is presumed to be seconds. So, the following are equivalent, and all mean “one hundred requests per five minutes”:
>
> ```
> 100/5m
> 100/300s
> 100/300
> ```

You thus can define these limits as:

```
from ratelimit.decorators import ratelimit

@ratelimit(key='user', rate='20/10s')
@ratelimit(key='user', rate='100/10m')
@ratelimit(key='user', rate='1000/d')
def some_view(request):
    pass
```

For class-based views (like a `ViewSet`), you can decorate it with the [**`@method_decorator`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.views.decorators.csrf.method_decorator), like:

```
django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from ratelimit.decorators import ratelimit

@method_decorator(ratelimit(key='user', rate='20/10s'), name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(ratelimit(key='user', rate='100/10m'), name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(ratelimit(key='user', rate='1000/d'), name='dispatch')
class MyViewSet(ViewSet):
    # ...
```

Comment: How can we set this rate limit for a viewset? Below is my viewset and i want to implement the ratelimit for this. 
class AssetParentTableViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = AssetParentTable.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AssetParentTableSerializer
    filterset_class = AssetParentTableFilter

Comment: @saadatali: you can apply `method_decorator`s on the `dispatch` method.

Answer (score 1):

Because I use below, not work for generic View.

```
@method_decorator(ratelimit(key='user', rate='1000/d'), name='dispatch')
class MyViewSet(ViewSet):
```

I find the other solution.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from ratelimit.decorators import ratelimit

class RateLimitForSecurity(View):
    @ratelimit(key='ip', rate='30/m')
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        was_limited = getattr(request, 'limited', False)
        if was_limited:
            return JsonResponse({"code": 1, 'msg': 'try many times'},json_dumps_params={'ensure_ascii':False})

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class IndexView(RateLimitForSecurity, generic.ListView):
      # same as before
```

Answer (score 0):

I was Working on this and found that you can override the throttle class function parse_rate and it can be customised by your need

```
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle
class ThirdPartyMonthlyThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'third_party_monthly'

    def parse_rate(self, rate):
        if rate is None:
            return None, None
        num, period = rate.split('/')
        num_requests = int(num)
        duration = int(period)*86400
        return num_requests, duration
```

```
'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'third_party_monthly': '3/30'
    }
```

This can be interpreted as 3 requests per month

Answer (score 0):

### You can do like this

```
from ratelimit.decorators import ratelimit
from http import HTTPStatus
```

```
@ratelimit(key='user_or_ip', rate='1/10m', method=['POST'])
def ajax_add_review(request, username):
    was_limited = getattr(request, 'limited', False)
        if was_limited:
            return JsonResponse({"error": 'limit crossed'}, status=HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
```